# EXM Messages sent with images as attachments on version 3.3

Tags: exm

In EXM 3.3, for some reason, all of our dispatched emails are getting sent where the images that included in our rich text field (which are all of them) are getting sent as attachments as well as showing up in the email.

> This was not the case in  ECM 2.2, and this is an upgraded solution.

**Is there a setting to change this so that the images are embedded into the email, not sent as attachments?**

[image]

Comment: I'm no EXM expert, but is it possible that the "Embed Images" flag is now on (in the root settings) and causing this?

Comment: Yeah I had same issue. It's what gatogordo mentioned. Go to newsletter root and untick embed images

Comment: What @Gatogordo said. This is documented here https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/30/setting_up_exm/the_manager_root/the_manager_root_settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the root settings of EXM as explained [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/setting_up_exm/the_manager_root/the_manager_root_settings).

[image]

The `Embed Images` checkbox controls whether to embed images in the message or to insert links to images. You might need to untick this.